# What is causing the links not to work with navgoco slide menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[I used a demo by jQueryRain](http://apps.komposta.net/jquery/navgoco/demo/) to build a collapsible menu with jQuery. When I was done, I realized that none of the links were working. When I went to the documentation page, I found that [many users were facing the same problem](http://www.komposta.net/article/navgoco#comments).

I looked around on StackOverflow and could not find anything that worked. I have tried the following:

*This redirects once the page loads*

`window.location = $(".link-click").attr("href");`

*These do nothing*

`$('link-click').trigger('click');` and  `$('.link-click')[0].click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd8rfLfp/4/). Do you mind sharing your code? You know you are not supposed to import their `demo.js` right? Also do you have something like

```
.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
});
```

in your code? `preventDefault()` blocks the default behaviour of anchor tag, which is to redirect. This is in their demo, which you may have copied and pasted? What did you assign to `active_menu_cb`?

Comment: No, I didn't import their demo.js and your example only works if `target="_blank"` is added to the `a` tag. This would be a super annoying navigation.

Comment: Oh weird... I removed the `target="_blank"` and changed the url from `http://www.google.com` to any other url and it worked. That's super weird?

Comment: @JohnRPerry, the only reason why I had `target="_blank"` in my fiddle is because it's running on jsfiddle, where the result is running in an iframe embedded in the corner of the page, and their iframe impose restrictions on redirecting away while inside an iframe. (See `sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin"`) I tried this code locally no my computer without iframe, and redirection without `target="_blank"` works fine. This is not an issue.